# gvim Linux - autocomplete plugin - enable / disable depending if the user is typing or not

Tags: autocompletion

I am using the [autocomplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) and I feel quite comfortable with it because it's minimalistic and simple.
But there is just a thing I dislike: sometimes it interferes with the mouse scrolling auto-changing some word...
Well, sometimes it also interferes when I jump from word to word in insert-mode, obligating me to undo the pop-up with direction keys...

Perhaps in this last weeks I am playing too much with vim, but my intention is to investigate the small plugin code to adjust it as my needs (if possible), enabling / disabling it depending if I am writing or not.

The pseudocode I thought is:

1. Start typing or entering insert-mode, execute `acp#enable()`
2. Stop typing or exit from insert-mode, execute `acp#disable()`

So is there any possible vim option that could enable it only when I am typing and disable after a short timeout when I stop/pause typing text ?

Is this too good to be true?

**EDIT:**

I just saw these interesting features:

```
TextChangedI            
                After a change was made to the text in the
                current buffer in Insert mode.
                Not triggered when the popup menu is visible.
                Otherwise the same as TextChanged.

InsertCharPre           
                When a character is typed in Insert mode,
                before inserting the char.
                The |v:char| variable indicates the char typed
                and can be changed during the event to insert
                a different character.  When |v:char| is set
                to more than one character this text is
                inserted literally.
                It is not allowed to change the text |textlock|.
                The event is not triggered when 'paste' is
                set.
```

And `help timeout`.

Comment: I don't use this plugin and I'm really not sure what you want to do is a good idea (that look like a hacky trick which might cause more problems than it solves, but once again I don't use this plugin so I might be wrong). However you might also be interested in [`:h CursorHoldI`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorHoldI).

Comment: Good to know this event. I actually set up an autocmd for `InsertCharPre` which calls `acp#enable()`, and other three autocmds for the events `InsertLeave, CursorHold, CursorHoldI`, and each one calls `acp#disable()`. Seems to be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

After having switched to gvim definetly since a few weeks, I think I have solved by my own:

```
 function! FeedCompletePopUp()
   
   if getline('.')[col('.') - 2] =~ '\w' && pumvisible() == 0
      return "\<C-N>\<C-P>"
   else
      return ""
   endif

endfunction
```

The following is taken and modified from `acp` plugin.

```
function AutoCompleteInoremap()
       
  let s:keysMappingDriven = [
        \ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        \ 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
        \ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
        \ 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
        \ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        \ '-', '_', '~', '^', '.', ',', ':', '!', '#', '=', '%', '$', '@', '<', '>', '/', '\' ]
  for key in s:keysMappingDriven
    execute "inoremap <silent> <nowait> ".key." ".key."<c-r>=FeedCompletePopUp()<CR>"
  endfor

endfunction


inoremap <expr> <silent> <nowait> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "<C-N>" : "<Tab>"
autocmd VimEnter * call AutoCompleteInoremap()
```

Let's see if popup completition is not shown unintentionally...